# matlab - winopen(), reading from the keyboard in fullscreem window

Tags: matlab, keyboard, windows-media-player

hi all
I wrote a short program that runs an avi file and records input from the keybpard while the avi is displaying. the problem is this. if the movie is in fill screen the program doesn't take the input from the keyboard. it takes the input only if the movie is minimizd.
this is my code

> >
>   close all
>   clc
>   winopen('c:/optic2.avi')
>   RT=[]
>   for i=1:1:5
>       tic
>       count=input('');
>       RT(i)=toc
>   end
>   xlswrite('c:/GS.xls',RT)

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [get input from keyboard while displaying an avi with matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733902/get-input-from-keyboard-while-displaying-an-avi-with-matlab)

Comment: 0% accepted answers, and re-posting the same question - neither are good form. Please have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

I usend KbChack from the psychtoolbox.