# Matlab: How to [programmatically] display images without the figure window blocking

Tags: matlab

I've written some machine learning code in Matlab, and I've added a piece of code to visualize the weights after each weight update.  Unfortunately, the figure window blocks until the train function exits.

Is there a straightforward way to get around this?

-Brian

Comment: Being a purely technical question, this belongs to StackOverflow (please don't repost it there, it will be automigrated if enough people vote to close it here).

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733902/get-input-from-keyboard-while-displaying-an-avi-with-matlab/4735497#4735497

Comment: Can you post the code around the section which displays the image?

Comment: Turns out there's a function called 'drawnow', but I essentially have to keep telling it to repaint otherwise it blocks until my code is done running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drawnow` is the most straightforward way to do this. It's not that the figure isn't being drawn each loop, it's more that the figure isn't being refreshed. This is more common in Matlab running on Linux & Mac, because the graphics is streamed through X11. Windows has a more native graphics UI and so this is less common (unless if the plot is too bulky and drawing takes time...). So, simply issue a drawnow command and you're all set.

**EDIT**

to use `drawnow` in a loop and force matlab to plot the figure on each iteration of the loop

```
for i=1:N %#begin loop
    <plot command here>
    drawnow
end       %#end loop
```

this way, `drawnow` is in the loop and your plot will be displayed on each iteration

Comment: As a follow-up to this, I'm curious whether there is a way to issue something like 'drawnow' that instructs it not to block, or attach a handler to the figure that will periodically tell it to draw

Comment: i don't understand your question. you can issue `drawnow` to make it draw every loop. i've edited my post to illustrate my point.

Comment: The code I'm working with is for training a neural net.  It's blocking while waiting for a conjugate gradient algorithm to finish running.  The equivalent step to what you've suggested is for the CG routine to periodically run drawnow(), which seems like a very hokey step to have to take to get around this problem.

If that's all I can do, then so be it.  I was just hoping for a little more flexibility out of something that costs thousands of dollars =)